# The p value for the random forest regression model

Tags: r, p-value, random-forest

So I was asked by a reviewer to provide the "P-value" for my random forest regression model.

I tried to do some research on this, and only found methods to produce p values for each split condition (like in 'party' package), and p-values for variable importance (like in 'rfPermute' package). I find it hard to trust the p-values for variable importance since some very important variables have p-values of >0.9.

Any input on how to generate the general "p-value" for random forest (if there is one) would be appreciated.

Comment: p-value of what?

Comment: So I reported the "% Var explained" and the reviewer asked me to provide the p-value.

Comment: I'll repeat, _"p-value of what"_?

Comment: You could always do a bootstrap of it, but why would the reviewer want this? It is perhaps the most irrelevant outcome of the RF.

Comment: @Repmat Indeed, the random forest is already bootstrapping a bunch of decision trees. It is likely that OP's reviewer is not familiar with random forests and how to interpret them. There's nothing inherently frequentist about it.

Comment: @markwhite, I agree completely. It has always been my experience that you should not argue with reviewers, let alone try to educate them about stats as they will a) ignore you, b)  reject the paper. Therefore it is much more easy to simply bootstrap on the raw data, and completely ignore what hypothetical distribution we are inferring about or whether the psudo R-square of an RF can be thought to come from anysuch distribution. But I digress.

Comment: The digression is appreciated; in my opinion, the peer-review process is one of the biggest hurdles in advancing statistical methodologies; many applied researchers don't continue their statistical education after finishing graduate school.

Comment: @MarkWhite: (obligatory snarky comment) some applied researchers appear to stop their statistical education after their undergraduate years and spend the rest of their academic life actively forgetting what they learned. [All this while loudly proclaiming that they don't need no stinkin' statisticians for their applications or studies.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz1fyhVOjr4&feature=related)

Comment: The question is based on a confusion, but that can be addressed in an answer. Moreover the existence of an upvoted answer implies this isn't too unclear to be answered. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When in doubt, simulate or permute.

In this specific case:

1. Randomly permute your dependent variable.
2. Fit a random forest.
3. Note the % variance explained.

Do steps 1-3 multiple times, say 1,000-10,000 times. You now have an empirical distribution of % variance explained through a random forest, under the null hypothesis of no relationship between your independent and dependent variable.

Insert the actual % variance explained in your original model into this distribution, and note which proportion of permutation-based "null" % variance explained values exceeds this true value. This proportion is your p value.

If you did the same thing in a standard linear regression model, you would (asymptotically) get the p value for the classical F test for variance explained.

As others write, your reviewer does not sound overly statistically savvy, but the approach I'm outlining above makes sense and should satisfy him. It's better than getting into an anonymous argument over the statistical competence of a reviewer, anyway.

Comment: What would be the steps for the simulation approach?

Comment: @Digio: I'd go with the permutation approach in this case.

Comment: Stephan - I still have 1 question on this method. How would you estimate the % variance explained per predictor from the RF importance score?

Comment: i would not calculate % variance explained *from the RF importance score*. I would assess % variance explained from the permutation analysis (by noting residual variance from the full model, and variance explained in a model with one predictor permuted), then define this as the variable's importance. Alternatively, use any other reasonable KPI, like Gini impurity reduction.

Comment: I see, thanks. By the way, by "RF importance score" I did mean Gini impurity or information gain.

Comment: I would say that would be necessary to perform permutation also on the features themselves in order to break the relationship between features and target (or dependent variable). This way the null hypothesis (that the % variance explained by rf is also explainable through fitting uncorrelated variables) would be properly set up. I am very interested in discussing this.

Comment: @JacoSolari: I do see your point, but I disagree. Yes, the "null behavior" of the RF under *uncorrelated* features might be interesting, but typically we would be more interested in the "null behavior" of the RF under *the features the way they are*. Which may be better or worse than under uncorrelated features. So I would not permute the features, but only the response.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Interesting point and I see what you mean. But then I was wondering: by permuting only the response don't we introduce a bias due to the fact that repeating the procedure say 10k times chances are that many of those permutation happen to be in a "good-enough" order and produce as a consequence a high % of explained variance?Maybe another approach could be to leave the features "the way they are" and testing them with RF against many independent samples of uniformly distributed random numbers with the same size and range as the response. Wouldn't that be less biased?

Comment: Well, I don't think there are all that many "good enough" permutations. The number of permutations is *huge* (it's actually hard to get a feeling for how many there are). And using a uniformly distributed random response has the problem that the distribution of the actual response may be far from uniform, even if we match ranges.

Comment: It's true that the number of permutation can be very very big, but it is still dependent on the sample size. That's why it seems to me that "resampling" the response at each iteration from a (uniform or better similar to the response one) distribution, might be more general. But it's just a feeling, I would need to run some simulations under controlled use-cases to convince myself of what could be the best/general approach.

Comment: It's an interesting an open topic I think, this paper for instance crafted a "Statistically interpretable importance index" for RF using feature permutation on OOB samples.. https://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pdupont/pdupont/pdf/benelearn_14.pdf